# Git Flow: Implications of merging to release branch instead of develop (aka easiest way to correct merge issues)

Tags: git, merge, git-flow

We have recently started using Git Flow branching strategy and somehow I was put in charge of being a "release manager".  I know Git Flow says feature branches should be merged into the `develop` branch but I'm wondering the implications of instead creating the `release/x.x.x` branch much earlier and merging features there and then testing from the release branch (and eventually merging to develop/master).  The reason would be we have some junior developers and if things go sideways it's easier to just delete the `release/x.x.x` branch and recreate / re-merge the feature branches.  If the developers continue to branch off `develop` the only downside I can think of is their code won't be aware of current developed/finished feature branches so merges to release may end up with more conflicts.  Am I overcomplicating this?

If I am can you point out some resources on how to deal with issues with merged code.  Are my only two choices essentially: 1) Potentially screw the timeline / hold the release and put the original developer on fixing the code issue and 2) resetting to a known good branch, force pushing, and make everyone sync up and remerge known good changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you that it's pretty easy to throw away `release` branches gone sideways, and the *reason* it's easy to do it is because most work isn't branching off of `release` and wouldn't be impacted by the branch going away. Your suggestion of having developers continue to branch off of `develop`, but merge into `release`, keeps the idea alive, but as you point out:

> the only downside I can think of is their code won't be aware of current developed/finished feature branches so merges to release may end up with more conflicts.

That is a **big** downside, and likely enough to make it insurmountable. It also means you can't use a rebase workflow, which is personally my favorite way to keep feature branches up to date with the target branch. (Note even while rebasing we still force a merge commit, ideally making a short bubble in the graph for every feature branch merge. This is sometimes called a "Semi-Linear" merge strategy.)

Both of your proposed ideas would work, but fortunately I think there's a better option.

My company had nearly the identical problem a few years ago, though in our case it wasn't just Junior devs that had the problem; we also had certain applications that were difficult to fully test before code was merged into `develop` and deployed to one of our shared testing environments. We solved this problem by adding another branch called `pre-develop` which was a throwaway branch that was reset to the latest `develop` every day. The `pre-develop` branch was built and deployed to a *Dev* environment for testing outside of a developer's laptop. Once they are happy with the results, they PR it into `develop`. After a while of doing this, we realized that the maintainers of Git do something very similar, which is called [gitworkflows](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows). (Sometimes it's also called gitworkflow; singular without the 's'.) [Additional reading here.](https://hackernoon.com/how-the-creators-of-git-do-branches-e6fcc57270fb) Since *gitworkflows* calls the throwaway branch `next`, we renamed `pre-develop` to `next` which in our case represents the "next changes to go into develop". We also changed our reset frequency to be once per week instead of daily, since developers wanted more time to finish their testing and to get their Product Owners to sign off on it. Now we consider our Git Branching Strategy to be a hybrid of *gitworkflows* and *Git Flow*.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to stick with what’s recommended in GitFlow so that it will not cause any future confusion.
I also would suggest to ask the developer who is in charge of the feature branch to fix the issue in the feature branch before creating a pull request to merge it to the develop branch. A release should always initiate from develop branch and the release branch should be merged in to the master.
You can have hook or setup permission for how it needs to be code reviewed before it’s been merged in the future.

Comment: Thank you.  In the scenario you describe is your team testing on the feature branches individually?  I understand if the issue(s) are known before merging but what happens when the issue(s) are not known and get merged, then has merges on top of it, and then is determined to have one or more issues.  It seems the only two choices are "roll forward" (fix it before the release is done however long that takes) or revert with a force push all the way to before the "bad" commit was introduced and have everyone resync.